# Right floated container results in line break

Tags: html, css, css-float

i am currently fighting with floated elements again.

please take a look at this jsfiddle: [float-issue](https://jsfiddle.net/e9bqoucg/1/)

```css
html {
  width: 100%
}
.container {
  /*width: 80%;*/
  /*margin: auto;*/
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.element {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: purple;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="float: right">
  <div style="float: left">HEADER</div>
  <div style="border: 1px solid green;">
    <div style="float: left">
      <div class="element">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
      <div class="element">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
      <div class="element">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

what i don´t understand is, why are the purple elements not next to the "HEADER" but on a new row? this issue came when adding the green bordered div element around the already floated div. i cant explain why this results in the new row? can anyony help me out?

what i thought would happen was:

1. the green bordered div is not floated so it fills the container div (and because is has no content (the elements inside are floated and therefore not part of the flow) shrinks to zero height).
2. the header div is floating "over" the green bordered div.
3. since the purple elements are left floated with another div, this div would float beside the floated header.

what am i missing?

Comment: Because you must set display: inline-block to the header div and the div that group the texts. By default the div is display: block.

Comment: hi @LuisP.A. why is that? both elements are already floating? and the surrounding element should not be relevant.

Comment: Floating have nothing with display... You can have float left with display: block or another display

Comment: The content inside the `.element` divs is causing the width of their container, combined with the width of the header, to be too large to fit inside the `.container` div.  Remove some text from one of these components, rerun the fiddle and watch it all fit nicely.

Comment: okay, but shouldn't´t the following floated elements float next to the header?

Comment: You are floating 2 things inside the `.container` - the header div and the green div.  The CONTENTS of the green div is too wide, so the whole green div is moving down.

Comment: @AlexMcMillan: thats the problem. the container is not constrained by a defined width.

Comment: @offline - see my answer below.  Float the header left, then the next div containing  the .element class divs... but DON'T float those individual divs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution with `display: inline-block`

```css
html {
  width: 100%
}
.container {
  /*width: 80%;*/
  /*margin: auto;*/
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.element {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: purple;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="float: right">
  <div style="float: left; display: inline-block;">HEADER</div>
  <div style="border: 1px solid green; display: inline-block;">
    <div style="float: left">
      <div class="element">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
      <div class="element">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
      <div class="element">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, he's trying to see the first "lorem ipsum" content immediately to the right of the word "HEADER".

Answer (score 0):

You are floating the "HEADER" div and the "green" div inside the container.  The contents of the green div are collectively too wide to fit to the right of the header.  If you remove `float: left` from the div *between* the green div and the `.element` divs, you will see the result you are after.

```
<div class="container" style="float: right">
    <div style="float: left">HEADER</div>
    <div style="border: 1px solid green;">
        <div>
            <div class="element">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.  </div>
            <div class="element">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.  lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
            <div class="element">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.  </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: doing this results in the first two purple boxes float next to the header and the last one is wrapped to the next line. the question is why is the outer box too small? i saw that in IE11 it is rendered "correctly".

Answer (score 0):

It's about the placement of your floats.  Float the header left first, then immediately after float the div containing the ".element" class divs.  But DON'T float the .element divs.  fiddle here:  https://jsfiddle.net/e9bqoucg/2/

```
 <div class="container" style="float: right">

    <div style="border: 1px solid green;">
        <div style="float: left;">HEADER</div>
        <div style="float: left">

            <div class="element">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.  </div>
            <div class="element">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.  lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
            <div class="element">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.  </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the elements were floated because they should layout next to each other. the surrounding div was floated because i wanted to force the whole three elements next to the header or wrapped to the next line if there was not enough space. it all worked fine until i added the green border div. question was: why forced this div, that also collapsed to 0 height, the floated div to the next line, that is to wrap? why does it result in the floated div´s not to fit in the container?

Comment: Well first, the border isn't around anything now because the floated elements are technically outside of that div (because of float property).  If you change the height to 20px of that green border div, for example, you'll see that.  In regards to adding that div changed layout, is because that new div is not floating, so it throws off the float: left "flow".  This is another fiddle where that new div has float: left, and you'll see the border issue still  https://jsfiddle.net/e9bqoucg/4/

Comment: if you move the green-border to a child element of that 2nd floated div, then put the '.element' class divs in that, I believe you'll get what you're looking for:  https://jsfiddle.net/e9bqoucg/5/

Comment: i know that div was not floating. but it collapsed and the inner floating divs are technically not part of that div. so why does this "throw off the float: left "flow"? why is is "breaking" the layout?

Comment: by the way i think this has something to do with width measurement of the containing right floated div. IE seems to measure this differently.

Comment: I think it is because that div you have with the green border is not floated, and is defaulted to display: block; which moves it down under the first header div.  If you can use chrome or ff, right click the header and 'inspect element'.  That will show the box model as you hover over different elements in the code. some more info on floating: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/01/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/

Comment: but the div is collapsed due to real content. the inner floated elements should float next to the header in my opinion.

Comment: It looks fine for me ... the header is on the left, all of the purple background elements are beside it to the right.  Is that not what you're looking for?

Comment: does it on this fiddle as well?  It looks fine for me in chrome and IE:  https://jsfiddle.net/e9bqoucg/5/

Comment: yes it does. but the "elements" are layed out vertically. but i think all the problems can be summarized by not establishing a consistent set of block formatting contexts. an unfloated div within a floated div with floated children seems to be "undefined" and a situation that browsers interpret differently.

Comment: maybe i just don't get what you're looking for... is this more like it?  https://jsfiddle.net/e9bqoucg/13/  displays purple elements inline.  Used "Display: table-cell" instead of floating on the parent divs

Comment: no, its way more simple: i want this: http://snag.gy/4XltA.jpg but i get this http://snag.gy/FE1JW.jpg. the "error" is due to fact that the div surrounding the purple elements is not floating. the problem is in FF and chrome. IE displays what i want. i think IE is interpreting the div differently because this "situation" is somewhat undefined in the CSS interpreting rules. this is because i said, there has to be a consistent set of BFC´s so that there is no room for interpretation.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/e9bqoucg/14/ (with preview window widened).  It also depends on what you want the content to do on smaller screens.  First, get the parent divs to be placed where you want (with float: left OR display: table-cell), then the purple element divs need to be inline-block or display: table-cell.  Do you want to avoid tables?  That's another option.  Is your goal to achieve that layout, or to understand why the browsers interpret differently.  There are a lot of things to consider.  for cross-browser inline-block: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-inline-block/

Comment: yeah, that's what i want. its a cool alternative. but the "implementation" with floats also worked for me. i only had to float the before unfloated div. generally i was trying to understand why the unfloated div created a line break. with seeing that IE does not create this line break, the goal was to understand why browsers interpret differently. is there a good resource for learning these css layout subtleties? the information i normally find is mostly superficial.